# What is OID,MIB? Check transfer amount by check_snmp

Tags: ubuntu, nagios, snmp

I am setting snmpd and try to check by check_snmp.

`snmpwalk -c public -v 2c localhost`

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "Linux ik1-325-22819 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.2.10
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (45994) 0:07:39.94
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = STRING: "Me <me@example.org>"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "ik1-325-22819"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = STRING: "Sitting on the Dock of the Bay"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0 = INTEGER: 72
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.1 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.11.3.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.2 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.15.2.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.3 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.10.3.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.4 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.5 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.16.2.2.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.6 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.49
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.7 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.8 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.50
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.9 = OID: iso.3.6.1.6.3.13.3.1.3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.10 = OID: iso.3.6.1.2.1.92
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.1 = STRING: "The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.2 = STRING: "The management information definitions for the SNMP User-based Security Model."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.3 = STRING: "The SNMP Management Architecture MIB."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.4 = STRING: "The MIB module for SNMPv2 entities"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.5 = STRING: "View-based Access Control Model for SNMP."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.6 = STRING: "The MIB module for managing TCP implementations"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.7 = STRING: "The MIB module for managing IP and ICMP implementations"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.8 = STRING: "The MIB module for managing UDP implementations"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.9 = STRING: "The MIB modules for managing SNMP Notification, plus filtering."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.10 = STRING: "The MIB module for logging SNMP Notifications."
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.1 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.2 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.3 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.4 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.5 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.6 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.7 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.8 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.9 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.4.10 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.2 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.4 = INTEGER: 4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.5 = INTEGER: 5
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.6 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 = STRING: "lo"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2 = STRING: "Red Hat, Inc. Device 0001"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.3 = STRING: "Red Hat, Inc. Device 0001"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.4 = STRING: "Red Hat, Inc. Device 0001"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.5 = STRING: "docker0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.6 = STRING: "br-6ec47ade44ad"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 24
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.2 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.3 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.4 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.5 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.6 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.1 = INTEGER: 65536
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.2 = INTEGER: 1500
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.3 = INTEGER: 1500
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.4 = INTEGER: 1500
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.5 = INTEGER: 1500
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.6 = INTEGER: 1500
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.1 = Gauge32: 10000000
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.2 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.3 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.4 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.5 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.6 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2 = Hex-STRING: 9C A3 BA 01 DF C3 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.3 = Hex-STRING: 9C A3 BA 03 66 63 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.4 = Hex-STRING: 9C A3 BA 04 ED 03 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.5 = Hex-STRING: 02 42 D7 D1 60 44 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.6 = Hex-STRING: 02 42 D8 24 17 95 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.2 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.3 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.4 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.5 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.6 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.2 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.3 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.4 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.5 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.6 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.1 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.2 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.3 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.4 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.5 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.6 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1 = Counter32: 3214378817
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.2 = Counter32: 1235162258
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.3 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.4 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.5 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.6 = Counter32: 286316
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.11.1 = Counter32: 135588065
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.11.2 = Counter32: 60939410
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.11.3 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.11.4 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.11.5 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.11.6 = Counter32: 4466
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.12.1 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.12.2 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.12.3 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.12.4 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.12.5 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.12.6 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.13.1 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.13.2 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.13.3 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.13.4 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.13.5 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.13.6 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14.1 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14.2 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14.3 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14.4 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14.5 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14.6 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.1 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.2 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.3 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.4 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.5 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.6 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.1 = Counter32: 3214378817
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.2 = Counter32: 2438196185
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.3 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.4 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.5 = Counter32: 0
.
.
.
```

Then I try to check_snmp.

```
./check_snmp -H localhost -O
No OIDs specified
```

Both are on the same host.

How can I find OID?? for check_snmp?

---

I want to know the transfer amount of interface `ens3`

However, honestly I don't know where to start.

I tried this.

```
$ snmpwalk -c public -v 2c localhost | grep ens3

iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.262146 = STRING: "network interface ens3"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.2 = STRING: "ens3"

$ ./check_snmp -H localost -O iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.2
No OIDs specified
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - the `snmpwalk` command returns a big list of OIDs. What is your problem? What are you trying to achieve? Edit your question to include further details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OIDs are **o**bject **id**entifiers. In numerical form, they are represented as strings of numbers separated by dots. They also have a symbolic form, where the numbers are mapped to keywords according to certain definitions.

The OID for `iso` is just `1`, since it identifies the first main branch off the root of the OID tree structure. You can start with any OID in symbolic form and then add numeric suffixes to it, if you don't have the corresponding symbolic information available.

Those definitions are stored in a standardized format in MIB files.

Your system apparently does not have the standard MIB files loaded, or your `snmpwalk` just isn't configured to use them. Otherwise, your snmpwalk output would look more like this:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: "Linux ik1-325-22819 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64"
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-TC::linux
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (45994) 0:07:39.94
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: "Me <me@example.org>"
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: "ik1-325-22819"
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: "Sitting on the Dock of the Bay"
SNMPv2-MIB::sysServices.0 = INTEGER: 72
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 = Timeticks: (1) 0:00:00.01
```

... and so on. A bit more informative that way, wouldn't you think?

A MIB file also defines other things besides names for OIDs: it also contains descriptions of the meanings of various values, and defines groups of OIDs that form information tables.

At OID `iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1` begins a table of network interface statistics, known as `IF-MIB::ifXTable`. The OIDs in the form `iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.N` form the first column of the table, identifying the name of each interface. The number of bytes transferred inwards through this interface is located in another column of the table, with OIDs of the form `iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.N` respectively, where N corresponds to the name of the interface. The number of bytes transferred outwards throught the interface are in yet another column, with OIDs of the form `iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.N`.

From your commands, I can see that the SNMP table row number (`N`) of your `ens3` interface is 2. Remember this; it will be used later on.

With the MIBs loaded and in use, you will be able to use the `snmptable` command to view such tables all at once in a meaningful way. For example, to view this table of interface statistics, you could run:

```
snmptable -c public -v 2c localhost IF-MIB::ifXTable
```

and have it all displayed in a table form. (This is a rather wide table, so if you want to try this, stretch your terminal window very wide first.)

The `snmptable` command will only work if the MIB file defining the respective table is available.

---

On Debian, and presumably also on Ubuntu, you can `sudo apt install snmp-mibs-downloader` which will be able to download an extensive set of standard MIBs from the authoritative standard sources on the internet, apply some erratas to them, and store them to `/var/lib/snmp/mibs/` for you. It might download them automatically on installing the package, or you might need to use the `sudo download-mibs` command.

To start using the downloaded MIBs, you may need to comment out one line in `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`:

```
# As the snmp packages come without MIB files due to license reasons, loading
# of MIBs is disabled by default. If you added the MIBs you can reenable
# loading them by commenting out the following line.
mibs :
```

Just comment out the last line or replace it with `mibs ALL`, or create `~/.snmp/snmp.conf` with a single line `mibs ALL` and you'll get to use the downloaded MIBs automatically.

There are also *vendor-specific MIBs*, that can describe vendor-specific OIDs with further information specific to a device of particular make and model. Typically, you can get these from the vendor's support download site, often as part of some vendor-specific management package.

---

With `check_snmp`, you would need to specify the OID using the `-o` (*lower case*) option. For example, to monitor the amount of data transferred inbound on your `ens3` network interface, you should run:

```
./check_snmp -H localhost -C public -P 2c -O -o iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.2
```

or if you have the MIBs installed:

```
./check_snmp -H localhost -C public -P 2c -O -o IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2
```

And for data transferred outbound:

```
./check_snmp -H localhost -C public -P 2c -O -o iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.2
```

or with the MIBs:

```
./check_snmp -H localhost -C public -P 2c -O -o IF-MIB::ifHCOutOctets.2
```

Comment: This is super helpful , I found change `mibs` -> `mibs : all` in  `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` and can get the data transfered